# Unable to run script after I run it through webpack. (Error: unable to locate global object)

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have a simple script.

**script/src/index.js**

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

console.log("working!")
...

exports = { createClient, createDevice };
```

**script/webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
};
```

**script/package.json**

```
{
    "name": "client",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "node-fetch": "^2.3.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^4.26.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack"
    }
}
```

Running the source code works fine

```
node script/src/index.js
working!
```

Now I want to bundle the source code with the npm dependency so I run

```
npm run build
```

Then I try running the built code

```
node script/dist/main.js
webpack:///./node_modules/node-fetch/browser.js?:11
    throw new Error('unable to locate global object');
    ^

Error: unable to locate global object
    at getGlobal (webpack:///./node_modules/node-fetch/browser.js?:11:8)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/node-fetch/browser.js?:14:14)
    at Object../node_modules/node-fetch/browser.js (/Users/xp025106/Dev/client-js/client/dist/main.js:97:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/xp025106/Dev/client-js/client/dist/main.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/index.js?:1:13)
    at Object../src/index.js (/Users/xp025106/Dev/client-js/client/dist/main.js:108:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/xp025106/Dev/client-js/client/dist/main.js:20:30)
    at /Users/xp025106/Dev/client-js/client/dist/main.js:84:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xp025106/Dev/client-js/client/dist/main.js:87:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

Why can I not run the built code the same way I could run the source code?

Comment: I think you want to run `npm run build` instead `node run build`, don't you?

Comment: @LucasCosta: Fixed! Unfortunately that was just a typo in my question so the problem persists.

Comment: since the application target is node, use `target: node`. Otherwise it is going to focus on hitting the browser

Comment: I have the same problem, did you figure out the solution?

Comment: @wewo: I don't think that I did. If I remember correctly I think I tried using another library instead (request library), and that worked.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering where to set `target: 'node'`: You have to add it to `module.exports` in `webpack.config.js`.